# Printing a string with a class in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Date{
private:
    unsigned int day;
    unsigned int month;
    string monthName;
    unsigned int year;
public:
    Date();
    void printNumeric() const;
    void printAlpha() const;
};
#endif
```

My header file

```
#include "Date.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


Date::Date(){
    month = 1;
    monthName = "January";
    day = 1;
    year = 1970;
}

void Date::printNumeric() const{
    cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year;
}

void Date::printAlpha() const{
    cout << Date::monthName << " " << day << ", " << year;
}
```

and the actual code.  My printNumeric function works fine according to the testbed but my printalpha is not producing the string month name.  Am I supposed to do something with monthName so that it would produce the user input for the month name?

Comment: Your code looks fine, you dont need to use `Date::monthName`, just `monthName` will be ok

Comment: You should use `cout << monthName << " " << day << ", " << year;` instead (no `Date::` prefix).

Comment: Some advice: 1) Include the headers you actually need (i.e. `<string>`and nothing else in your header file, `<iostream>` in your `.cpp` file. 2) do not say `using namespace std;`, *especially* in a header file.

Comment: Your code works just fine. See here. http://ideone.com/LEidk3 (But it's a very bad idea to have a `using namespace` in a header file)

Comment: g++4.8 does not complain about Date::monthName

Comment: "my printalpha is not producing the string month name" - so what is it producing? It looks fine to me (although the `Date::` is superfluous, as others have pointed out, and it might not compile since the header doesn't include `<string>`).

Comment: The testbed says that it is just producing a blank.

Comment: Can you confirm that your code compiles, despite the absence of some of the required headers? I am not saying it can't compile, but it isn't guaranteed to, so better cross-check that.

Comment: It compiles as it is.  what headers am I missing?

Comment: @RikoKurahashi I already told you about the headers.

Comment: @marcin_j g++4.6, g++4.9 and clang++ don't complain too.

Answer (score 3):

Remove *Date::* and it should work

Comment: a: Where? b: Why? c: what do you expect happens with "Date::" there?

Comment: The test bed says that my monthName is not producing anything so I was thinking that I should directly use Date:: to see if it would produce the string name for a month.

Answer (score 0):

Using Date:: would be the same as using *this* or the *member* variable alone as long as you are within the class scope.

but you are better off using

```
cout << this->monthName << " " << day << ", " << year;
```

or

```
cout << monthName << " " << day << ", " << year;
```

Use `Date::` when you have a static method to call or a public member to initialize outside the class scope for instance.

by the way, just in case you have another language background, string is part of *iostream*.
So, do not use `using namespace std;` but `std::cout` you would then realize it when the compiler produces an error.